# Scroll UICollectionView at a given speed using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement a similar photo selection method to the stock iOS photos app. This works using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which disables the scroll on the `UICollectionView`. In the stock photos app, it seems like when the pan reaches the top or bottom of the screen the scroll view starts scrolling at a given speed and the closer to the edge of the screen, the quicker the scroll.

It doesn't seem as if there's an API to scroll at a given speed in a `UIScrollView` or `UICollectionView`. Is there any clever way I could do this with the existing methods such as `scrollToVisibleRect` or setting the content offset within an animation block? I'm worried that whilst these may work, they will be jerky in their movement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `SpeedScrollableCollectionViewController` for this and controlling it using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (not relevant to the question

```swift
class SpeedScrollableCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    private var lastFrameTime: CFTimeInterval?
    
    private var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
   
    override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }
    
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
   
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    var scrollSpeed: CGPoint = .zero {
        didSet {
            guard scrollSpeed != .zero else {
                displayLink?.isPaused = true
                return
            }
            guard displayLink == nil else {
                lastFrameTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
                displayLink?.isPaused = false
                return
            }
            lastFrameTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
            displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(updateContentOfffset))
            displayLink?.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func updateContentOfffset() {
        
        defer {
            lastFrameTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        }
        
        guard let lastFrameTime = lastFrameTime else { return }
        
        let dt = CACurrentMediaTime() - lastFrameTime
        let dx = scrollSpeed.x * CGFloat(dt)
        let dy = scrollSpeed.y * CGFloat(dt)
        
        var currentOffset = collectionView.contentOffset
        currentOffset.x += dx
        currentOffset.y += dy
        collectionView.setContentOffset(currentOffset, animated: false)
    }
}
```